# How many Spark Session to create?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We are building a data ingestion framework in pyspark.
The first step is to get/create a sparksession with our app name. The structure of *dataLoader.py* is outlined below.

```
spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName('POC') \
            .enableHiveSupport() \
            .getOrCreate()
 #create data frame from file
 #process file
```

If i have to execute this *dataLoader.py* concurrently for loading different files, would having the same spark session cause an issue?
Do I have to create a separate spark session for every ingestion?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is to create a Spark session once, share it among several threads and enable FAIR job scheduling. Each of the threads would execute a separate spark job, i.e. calling collect or other action on a data frame. The optimal number of threads depends on complexity of your job and the size of the cluster. If there are too few jobs, the cluster can be underloaded and wasting its resources. If there are too many threads, the cluster will be saturated and some jobs will be sitting idle and waiting for executors to free up.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't create multiple spark session. Spark session should be created only once per spark application. Spark doesn't support this and your job might will fail if you use multiple spark session in the same spark job. Here is the [SPARK-2243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243) where spark has closed the ticket saying it won't fix it.

If you want to load different files using the `dataLoader.py`there are 2 options

1. Load and process files sequentially. Here you load one file at a time; save that to a dataframe and process that dataframe.
2. Create different `dataLoader.py` script for different files and run each spark job in parallel. Here each spark job gets its own sparkSession.

Comment: Hi Avishek,  We are using spark-submit to call the dataLoader.py to process our job.  And the dataLoader.py takes the target table name as an argument.  So if I call spark-submit twice, that would mean having two spark applications?  If yes, is this approach recommended.  We are basically planning on ingesting a lot of files using the same script.

Comment: Yes that will work, you need to do spark submit twice, that will create 2 spark  applications. That is the correct way to go about this issue

Comment: @Avishek, are you sure in the 2nd approach above, each job gets separate sparkSession? My understanding is that, it will try to get a spark session if there is one already created (reuse the existing) or create a new one and assigns the newly created SparkSession. Is my understanding not right?

Answer (score 0):

Each spark job is independent and there can only be one instance of SparkSession ( and SparkContext )  per JVM. You won't be able to create multiple session instances.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new spark application for every file which is certainly possible as each spark application would have 1 corresponding spark session, it is not the recommended way though (usually).You can load multiple files using the same spark session object which is preferred (usually).

Comment: Can you please eloborate on why creating spark applications per file is not recommended.

Comment: Starting a spark application has an overhead where executors are spawned and resource negotiation takes place which takes a substantial amount of time. That is why its better to have 1 spark application for say 10 files rather than creating 10 spark applications for 10 different files. 

You can create a spark session and then have threads to do action on different files using the same spark session that way you face the overhead only once for all your files.